# How to make px size responsive?

Tags: css, responsive-design

I was looking at the user display pictures in feeds of Quora and Facebook.

These pictures have a fixed size of:

```
width: 40px;
height: 40px;
```

When I change the browser size the page is responsive,
 and the size of these pictures stay same, `40px` and `40px`.

What else is used to keep the pictures' size same?

From what I know, `px` is not dependent on the parent element.

Comment: css relative vs absolute units - have a search for that

Comment: You'd want to use relative units such as `em`, `rem`, or percentages. As the name suggests, this is relative to the size of the parent container.

Comment: yeah I know about relative units...I only want to know what Facebook and Quora do to keep the picture responsive when there sizes are defined in 'px'?

Comment: Propably using @media queries?

Comment: You can safely use fixed sizes inside a responsive element. Although you want to keep it below the smallest viewport you want to support. It's not mandatory to always use relative units. Although it can produce overflow bugs in the future.

Comment: @FrederikMoller but media query should also change the picture size, it stays same 40px and is also not overridden.

Answer (score 0):

Pixel ratios can be used in responsive design by defining pixel density.

For example, this is commonly done in the header section of most HTML documents:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width>
```

With this tag, devices with a pixel density of 2.0 will modify a pixel width from 640px to 320px. This is one of many methods that pixels ratios will adjust based on a user's device/viewport.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are retrieving an image of 40px width and 40px height you won't be able to resize it without lossless in the image information(pixels) so you will need to check Facebook API in order to know how to get the images in larger size first! then you will think about making it looks good on other devices.

Answer (score 0):

I use a sass mixin to maintain the aspect ratio of certain elements. Mine is a modified version of Chris Coyier's, found here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/sass/maintain-aspect-ratio-mixin/

Or, if you mean they are maintaining the actual size of 40x40px regardless of windw size, they could just have `max-width: 40px; min-width: 40px;` declared on the element. Or perhaps `<img src="#" width=40 height=40>` set on their element tags.